# Notepad++ Shortcuts File Location

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, user-accounts

I have two accounts on my Windows 10 machine.

On one, the notepad++ shortcuts stored in users/user1/appdata/roaming/notepad++/shortcuts.xml work fine.

On the other account, the shortcuts defined in users/user2/appdata/roaming/notepad++/shortcuts.xml are not available.

This makes me sad. Can anyone explain how user2 can make those shortcuts work please?

Answer (score 2):

I install notepad++ on user1, and create user2, switch user2 and shortcuts.xml also work.

On notepad++ installed, will create two shortcuts.xml file, first is install dir, like

> C:\Program Files\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

second is user dir like

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

if switch new user and open notepad++, soft will create new `shortcuts.xml` in current user dir, like

> C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

you can modify current notepad++ shortcut and look the three shortcuts.xml file who's last modify time is nearyly, if no shortcut.xml file change, try uninstall and install again maybe useful